# Assigning an atribute from an array item while looping through a recordset

Tags: arrays, loops, vbscript, asp-classic, recordset

I'm using a loop on a record set to generate a JSON (works fine) but I need to assign a custom class from an array which will iterate by one every time the loop continues and then restarts if there are more items in the record set than there are in the array.

Here's my code:

```
    cnArray=array("Blue", "Magenta", "DarkViolet", "Red", "Orange", "Green", "Yellow", "Turq", "MidBlue")
'//that's my array of custom class names

    AjaxSQL="SELECT Title,StartDate,EndDate FROM TBL;"
    set AjaxRS=Myconn.execute(AjaxSQL)
    set AjaxSQl=nothing
'//that's my recordset set up

    classname=cnArray(0)
'// specifying the first item in the array to be my variable name which will be used in the loop

    AjaxJSON="["
    Do while not AjaxRS.eof
        AjaxJSON=AjaxJSON&"{'start': '"&AjaxRS("StartDate")&"', 'end': '"&AjaxRS("EndDate")&"', 'content': '"&AjaxRS("Title")&"', 'className': '"&classname&"'},"
        AjaxRS.MoveNext
    loop
    AjaxJSON=left(AjaxJSON,(len(AjaxJSON)-1))
    AjaxJSON=AjaxJSON&"]"
    response.write(replace(AjaxJSON,"'",""""))
'// the loop that generates the JSON
```

As I've said, the loop works fine, the JSON is valid but I can't figure out how to make the classname variable change to the next one in the array and then restart.

Any ideas are more than welcome (debating of doing it at the SQL call)

Thanks

elboffor

::edit::

as requested, below here is what my current JSON looks like:

```
[{
    "start": "/Date(1466553600000)/",
    "end": "/Date(1466985600000)/",
    "content": "test",
    "className": "Blue"
}, {
    "start": "/Date(1467244800000)/",
    "end": "/Date(1467244800000)/",
    "content": "Pennyroyal Tea",
    "className": "Blue"
}]
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
[{
    "start": "/Date(1466553600000)/",
    "end": "/Date(1466985600000)/",
    "content": "test",
    "className": "Blue"
}, {
    "start": "/Date(1467244800000)/",
    "end": "/Date(1467244800000)/",
    "content": "Pennyroyal Tea",
    "className": "Magenta"
}]
```

as you can see the second response should be the second iteration of the array, as more are added it will go through the array until it reaches MidBlue and then starts the array again with Blue

Comment: Add to the question how should the expected JSON look like.

Comment: all edited with the current JSON and what I want it to look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    cnArray=array("Blue", "Magenta", "DarkViolet", "Red", "Orange", "Green", "Yellow", "Turq", "MidBlue")
    cnTotal=UBound(cnArray)+1
    AjaxSQL="SELECT Title,StartDate,EndDate FROM TBL;"
    set AjaxRS=Myconn.execute(AjaxSQL)
    set AjaxSQl=nothing

    cnIndex = 0
    AjaxJSON="["
    Do while not AjaxRS.eof
        AjaxJSON=AjaxJSON&"{'start': '"&AjaxRS("StartDate")&"', 'end': '"&AjaxRS("EndDate")&"', 'content': '"&AjaxRS("Title")&"', 'className': '"&cnArray(cnIndex Mod cnTotal)&"'},"
        AjaxRS.MoveNext
        cnIndex = cnIndex + 1
    loop
    AjaxJSON=left(AjaxJSON,(len(AjaxJSON)-1))
    AjaxJSON=AjaxJSON&"]"
    response.write(replace(AjaxJSON,"'",""""))
```

Using `cnIndex` counter variable and `Mod` operator allows to get the necessary element. While `cnIndex` is increasing, `Mod` operator divides counter `cnIndex` by quantity of elements in the array `cnTotal` and returns the remainder, which is always between 0 and last array element index.

Comment: appears to work spot on buddy, thank you :)

would you be so kind as to add a few comments so I know I fully understand what's going on here for the future please?

also I assume once it reaches the end of the array it will start again from cnIndex0?

Comment: @elboffor I added short description.